# RPi hanging if Ethernet unplugged

Tags: networking

I’ve configured a RPi as a wireless router according to [this link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Raspberry-Pi-3-As-Router/)If everything is connected. All is well unless I boot without the Ethernet cable plugged in and internet connected, in which case it waits until I plug the cable in. I don’t need internet connectivity since I just need to connect local RPi into a network. What setting do I need to change to rectify this?

**Update** with information from comments:
The boot sequence stops, and does not continue, until the Ethernet cable is plugged in with a live Internet connection.

I can’t say exactly where in the boot sequence, but I suspect it’s ti do with the configuration of the dhcpd.conf file which allows the Wi-fi dongle to be hot plugged but sets up the eth0 interface differently. IIRC when a Pi boots normally there is a point in the boot sequence when the Pi waits for a network connection but times out after a short while and places the waiting process into the background.

Comment: Please clarify what "it waits" refers to.

Comment: The boot sequence stops until the Ethernet cable is plugged in with a live Internet connection

Comment: <_< *At what point?*  Your question is written as if people will recognize the scenario based on your bare minimum description.  That could happen, but not likely, so it might behoove you to add **some details** that might be recognizable or ring a bell with someone.

Comment: @goldilocks I can’t say exactly where in the boot sequence, but I suspect it’s ti do with the configuration of the dhcpd.conf file which allowemphasized text the Wi-fi dongle to be hot plugged but sets up the eth0 interface differently. Iirc when a Pi boots normally there is a point in the boot sequence when the Pi waits for a network connection but times out after a short while and places the waiting process into the background

Comment: Take `ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` out of /boot/cmdline.txt

Comment: Please add additional information to the question instead of using comments. You can edit the question. Not all people will read extended comments to understand the question.

Comment: What Raspberry Pi and what operating system do you use? How long the boot sequence stops? Longer than 10 minutes? Can you please edit your question and add the output of this command to it: `systemd-analyze blame | head` after the boot sequence has stopped some time.

Comment: And how am I supposed to run any command while the Pi is still in the middle of its boot sequence?

Comment: Boot with unplugged ethernet cable, wait 3 minutes, then plug in the ethernet cord and after login execute the command. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.